# KnockoutJS-Validation: initialization isn't being applied

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I using knockout-validation plugin. But when I initialize custom options:

```
viewModel{
    model:{
       id: ko.observable(''),
       title: ko.observable('').extend({required: {message: mymessage}})
    },
    testFunc: function(){
        ....
    }
}

...

ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel, document.getElementById('mainView'));

ko.validation.configure({
       errorMessageClass: 'error-message',
       errorElementClass: 'error',
       decorateInputElement: true
});

this.viewModel.model.errors = ko.validation.group(this.viewModel.model);
```

they aren't being applied. If validating model, and show errors - getting default plugin message without my class `error-message` and input isn't decorated with `error` class.

But they are applied when I added them to markup:

```
<div id="mainView">

   <table data-bind="with: model">     

      <tbody data-bind="validationOptions {errorMessageClass: 'error-message',
          errorElementClass: 'error',
          decorateInputElement: true}">

          ...  
          <td>
               <input data-bind="value: title" type="text">
          </td> 
          ...

      </tbody>

   </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Try to call `ko.validation.configure` **before** `ko.applyBindings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to the validation plugin provides some of its functionality and your setup applied correctly you need to configure the validation plugin before any of the bindings applied so **before** calling `ko.applyBindings`.

So you just need to change the order of those lines:

```
ko.validation.configure({
       errorMessageClass: 'error-message',
       errorElementClass: 'error',
       decorateInputElement: true
});

ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel, document.getElementById('mainView'));
```